# mysql: how to query the ratio in one table

Tags: mysql

I have four records:

```
id   instance_id    type    value
1     a              used     1
2     a              total    5
3     b              used      2
4     b              total    6
```

I want to calculate raito  used/total for each instance_id

the result should be

a:             1/5
   b:            2/6

how can I query ?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Is this homework?

Comment: I selected all the records and calculated with program. But I want to know if I could get the result using sql statement?

Comment: 2/6 = 1/3 !!!!! Otherwise, there's no 'calculation' as such here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below

```
SELECT instance_id ,
SUM(CASE WHEN type= 'used' THEN value ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN type= 'total' THEN value ELSE 0 END) 
FROM t 
GROUP BY instance_id
```

Comment: what value do you want if total is zero, according to your requirement you can write one more case statement before doing that dividing operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT instance_id ,
CONCAT(SUM(CASE WHEN type= 'used' THEN value ELSE 0 END),'/',SUM(CASE WHEN type= 'total' THEN value ELSE 0 END) )
FROM t 
GROUP BY instance_id
```